# Creating a github repository from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I am creating a new app and I want to be able to create a repository from the command line to be able to add commits without having to go to github and create a repo. I am totally noobian. is it possible? and if so how? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of creating a repo, you may want to add a branch to an existing repo. That way you can take advantage of compression and file content deduplication.

Comment: Too tired to write answer. Here is a rather long winded blog entry I wrote on the subject though: http://eggmatters.com/post.php?pid=28

Comment: what will compression and file content deduplication do for me? Does this advise stand if I want to create a new app or only if I want to edit an existing one. Is it convention to have one repo per app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use git, then it is fairly straightforward, but you won't go far without going through some tutorial. I highly recommend [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) by Scott Chacon. At least go through chapter 2 and perhaps chapter 3. To answer your questions though: Git is a distributed versioning system so you definitely do not need a repo in GitHub - you can create a repo on your own harddrive and then push it to any other repos (i.e. you could create a GitHub repository later and publish your repository there - it will be an exact clone!).

To create a repo you invoke a command: `git init` or `git init repoName` - the former creates the repo in current folder, the latter creates a new one named "repoName".

When you are ready to create a first commit invoke `git add .` to add all files to index (think of it as an area where you prepare what will go into the next commit) and the git commit -m "Commit message". nstead of adding all files you could also choose files to commit individualy by `git add path/to/file`

You will need at least some basics with git covered though before you can start using it comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

for github you could try [hub](https://github.com/github/hub#git-create) - is a command line tool that wraps git in order to extend it with extra features and commands that make working with GitHub easier.

Examples from doc:

```
$ git create
[ repo created on GitHub ]
> git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USER/CURRENT_REPO.git

# with description:
$ git create -d 'It shall be mine, all mine!'

$ git create recipes
[ repo created on GitHub ]
> git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USER/recipes.git

$ git create sinatra/recipes
[ repo created in GitHub organization ]
> git remote add origin git@github.com:sinatra/recipes.git
```